# lubuntu wont open unless I run specific commands in emergency mode

Tags: boot, usb, lubuntu

I have lubuntu installed on a USB (not burned).

today I accidentally pulled out the USB before I turned off the pc and the installation broke. every time I boot into the USB it boots in emergency mode.

I found [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748289/how-to-repair-ubuntu-installation-after-interrupted-dist-upgrade-without-losing) and followed the instructions of the first answer up to the point it tells you to `apt-get update`. after that point i can just `exit` and it will boot into the OS correctly.

what I want to ask is how can i make it boot correctly without redoing the steps every single time?

Comment: 1. Is there a persistent live or installed system on the USB drive? See [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389) ;  2. I think the file system is damaged because buffered data had not been saved to the drive, when you unplugged it. So you could try to repair the file system, when booted from another drive. [This link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986) might help; 3. If too much damage, try to save/recover the most valuable files (maybe you can save the whole home directory), and reinstall, or restore from a backup. Good luck :-)

Comment: @sudodus I think the second link will work. Thank you! if you post this as an answer ill accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I think the file system is damaged because buffered data had not been saved to the drive, when you unplugged it.

  So you could try to repair the file system, when booted from another drive. This link might help,

  [Repair the partition table and file system of a pendrive](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986)
- If too much damage, try to save/recover the most valuable files (maybe you can save the whole home directory), and reinstall, or restore from a backup. Good luck :-)