# KDE Neon Ubuntu crash after update

Tags: command-line, kde, update-manager, startup

After my attempt to update to Ubuntu 18.04 I run into a problem. When i was restarted my system, Ubuntu started in terminal mode. I want to fix this problem without reinstalling my OS. I tried to launch from grub recovery mode, but it did not help.

Then i tried to type commands, which are shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748289/how-to-repair-ubuntu-installation-after-interrupted-dist-upgrade-without-losing). I got a errors after running this command.

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

Here they are:

```
dpkg: error processing package neon-desktop (--configure)
dependencies problem - leaving unconfigured
```

I tried to run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall neon-desktop`, but I got the following unmet dependencies errors.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall neon-desktop
[sudo] password for kocmuk:  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
neon-desktop : Depends: baloo-kf5 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: breeze but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: distro-release-notifier but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: kde-cli-tools but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: khotkeys but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: kio but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: kio-extras but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: kkmenuedit but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: ksysguard but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: distro-release-notifier but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: kwin but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: kwrited but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: plasma-desktop but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: powerdevil but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: sdd-theme-breeze but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: systemsettings but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: xorg but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: ark but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: bluedevil but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: dolphin but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: drkonqi-pk-debug-installer but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: frameworkintegration but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: gwenview but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: kde-config-gtk-style but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: kde-config-plymouth but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: kde-config-sddn but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: kde-spectacle but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: kdegraphics but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: kdialog but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: konsole but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: kscreen but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: ksshaskpass but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: kwin-addons but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: kwrite but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: milou but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: okular but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: plasma-browser-integration but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: plasma-calendar-addons but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: plasma-dataengines but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: plasma-discover but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: plasma-discover-updater but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: plasma-nm but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: plasma-pa but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: plasma-runners-addons but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: plasma-vault but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: plasma-wallpapers-addons but it is not going to be installed  
               Recommends: plasma-widgets-addons but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: plasma-workspace-wayland but it is not going to be installed                         
               Recommends: polkit-kde-agent-1 but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: print-manager but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: user-manager but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: xserver-xorg-input-evdev but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: xserver-xorg-input-synaptics but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Please post error messages from the last command. It is crucial to see what the system reports.

Comment: @gmt42 here you are, sorry for photo. I updeted my question

Answer (score 1):

With any upgrade to a new Ubuntu version, third-party repositories and ppa's will be disabled. You need to check if they support the new version (in your case `bionic`) and change them to the new version. Then you can reenable them.

---

Find the relevant entry for the KDE Neon repository in the `sources.list` file

Should look something like this:

```
# deb http://archive.neon.kde.org/user xenial main
```

Dependent on how you installed it you will find it either in  `/etc/apt/sources.list` or (more likely) in one of the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

You can also use the following command to find the file:

```
grep -rlF 'archive.neon.kde.org' /etc/apt/
```

Change `xenial` to `bionic`, and reenable the repository by removing the `#` from that line.

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
```