# Error to start ubuntu 18.04 ( linux )

Tags: 18.04, .desktop, session

I have installed Ubuntu 17.10 and all software works fine. I made an update from 17.10 to 18.04 and it was successfully. I need to use Nvidia driver and CUDA for some deep learning projects. So some package are installed and other not. I follow some topics on the web and I modified `/etc/apt/sources.list` and from this modification, unfortunately, I typed wrong command that remove all Ubuntu features and software:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

When I try update or upgrade or `apt-get install -f`, I get errors that package are corrupted , and i get differentes errors. I tried to use Ubuntu backup option from grub menu. I get desktop graphic of Ubuntu but when I tried to enter with my login and password I get this error:

```
failed to start session
```

How can I solve those errors?

Comment: similar question was asked here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/748289/how-to-repair-ubuntu-installation-after-interrupted-dist-upgrade-without-losing - check it out

Comment: I had followed all those steps but the problem persist

Comment: if you really messed up your ubuntu installation it's better to reinstall it from scratch, backing up your home directory. You might want to install separate fresh ubuntu on diffrent partititon, then mount bricked system and move everything you need.

Comment: If i reboot my pc now ( remind that i have windows 10 and ubuntu 18.04 ) and i put my usb that have ubuntu 18.04 burned , problem it will be resolved?

Comment: It's safe to boot live cd via pendrive, whenever do you want. However you can't recover your system from pendrive. What you can do is to reinstall it from scratch, overwriting existing ubuntu installation. Ubuntu should also reinstall grub (bootloader) and detect your Windows 10 installation, so you'll end up with double boot option when you start your PC.

Comment: That is it , i don't want to get troubles when i start my pc so i search fo a solution to restore ubuntu , no problem if there is a risk to didn't get my data after reinstalling it

Comment: Then just re-install it on top of your current ubuntu installation. Just make sure that you choose right option during partitioning, that will leave you windows 10 untouched. As always: it's better to have backups.

Comment: @abdou31 **I modified /etc/apt/sources.list**: What kind of modifications? You must know that modifying repository information without knowing what actually you are doing can lead to non-availability of updates and packages from official repositories. Go to TTY mode using Ctrl+Alt+F3 and see what are the contents of  `/etc/apt/sources.list` using `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: @Kulfy I followed a solution proposed by someone in the web for installing nvidia drivers and i modified sources.list to get ubuntu drivers updates

Comment: I'm not sure which guide you followed. Can you please provide the above said content?