# Zeal Not working after ubuntu upgraded from 19.10 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, qt

Some days ago I upgraded Ubuntu from 19.10 to 20.04. After upgrading all things work fine except Zeal documentation browser. **I clearly says that to update qt5.** But I don't know how to update it. The error message is **Executable 'zeal' requires Qt 5.12.5, found Qt 5.12.4.**

[image: Error Message]

#### Edit

**I installed zeal from software center**

#### Output of Commands

```bsh
parikshit@Vostro-5568:~$ which zeal
/usr/bin/zeal
parikshit@Vostro-5568:~$ dpkg -l | grep zeal
ii  zeal                                              1:0.6.1-1build1                            amd64        Simple offline API documentation browser
parikshit@Vostro-5568:~$ apt-cache policy zeal
zeal:
  Installed: 1:0.6.1-1build1
  Candidate: 1:0.6.1-1build1
  Version table:
 *** 1:0.6.1-1build1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
parikshit@Vostro-5568:~$ ldd /usr/bin/zeal | grep local
parikshit@Vostro-5568:~$
```

#### Output of `ldd /usr/bin/zeal`

```bsh
parikshit@Vostro-5568:~$ ldd /usr/bin/zeal
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff84385000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007fbfd6a54000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007fbfd650d000)
    libsqlite3.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007fbfd63e4000)
    libQt5Concurrent.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Concurrent.so.5 (0x00007fbfd63db000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007fbfd5df5000)
    libQt5Network.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007fbfd5c34000)
    libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fbfd5af5000)
    libQt5X11Extras.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5X11Extras.so.5 (0x00007fbfd5aee000)
    libxcb-keysyms.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-keysyms.so.1 (0x00007fbfd5ae9000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fbfd5abf000)
    libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5 (0x00007fbfd5a72000)
    libQt5WebKit.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebKit.so.5 (0x00007fbfd2c72000)
    libarchive.so.13 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libarchive.so.13 (0x00007fbfd2bae000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fbfd29cd000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fbfd29b2000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbfd27c0000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fbfd279d000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fbfd264e000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fbfd2630000)
    libicui18n.so.63 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.63 (0x00007fbfd234e000)
    libicuuc.so.63 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.63 (0x00007fbfd217a000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fbfd2174000)
    libpcre2-16.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-16.so.0 (0x00007fbfd20f1000)
    libdouble-conversion.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdouble-conversion.so.3 (0x00007fbfd20db000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fbfd1fb1000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbfd7213000)
    libGL.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fbfd1f29000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007fbfd1ef1000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007fbfd1dec000)
    libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fbfd1de6000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fbfd1ddc000)
    libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 (0x00007fbfd1d63000)
    libQt5Quick.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5 (0x00007fbfd18a4000)
    libQt5WebChannel.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebChannel.so.5 (0x00007fbfd1883000)
    libQt5Positioning.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Positioning.so.5 (0x00007fbfd17f5000)
    libQt5Sensors.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Sensors.so.5 (0x00007fbfd17b3000)
    libwoff2dec.so.1.0.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwoff2dec.so.1.0.2 (0x00007fbfd17a4000)
    libjpeg.so.8 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007fbfd171f000)
    libwebp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.6 (0x00007fbfd14b6000)
    libhyphen.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhyphen.so.0 (0x00007fbfd14af000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007fbfd12f5000)
    libxslt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1 (0x00007fbfd12b3000)
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fbfd10d6000)
    libgstapp-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstapp-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fbfd10c4000)
    libgstbase-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fbfd1046000)
    libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fbfd0eff000)
    libgstpbutils-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstpbutils-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fbfd0ec1000)
    libgstaudio-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstaudio-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fbfd0e44000)
    libgsttag-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsttag-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fbfd0e04000)
    libgstvideo-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fbfd0d53000)
    libgstfft-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstfft-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fbfd0d46000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fbfd0ce9000)
    libQt5Qml.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5 (0x00007fbfd0833000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fbfd0828000)
    libnettle.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.7 (0x00007fbfd07ec000)
    libacl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1 (0x00007fbfd07e1000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fbfd07ba000)
    libzstd.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 (0x00007fbfd0711000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007fbfd06f0000)
    libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007fbfd06db000)
    libicudata.so.63 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.63 (0x00007fbfcecea000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fbfcec77000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007fbfcebbf000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007fbfceb8b000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007fbfceaca000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007fbfcea9d000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007fbfcea83000)
    libwoff2common.so.1.0.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwoff2common.so.1.0.2 (0x00007fbfcea7e000)
    libbrotlidec.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlidec.so.1 (0x00007fbfcea6f000)
    libicuuc.so.66 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.66 (0x00007fbfce887000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fbfce881000)
    libmount.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1 (0x00007fbfce821000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fbfce7f6000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fbfce7da000)
    liborc-0.4.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liborc-0.4.so.0 (0x00007fbfce755000)
    libffi.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007fbfce74b000)
    libbrotlicommon.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlicommon.so.1 (0x00007fbfce728000)
    libicudata.so.66 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.66 (0x00007fbfccc67000)
    libblkid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007fbfccc0e000)
    libpcre2-8.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007fbfccb7e000)
parikshit@Vostro-5568:~$
```

Comment: How did you installed zeal first time? Please add the output of `which zeal`, `dpkg -l | grep zeal`, `apt-cache policy zeal` to the question.

Comment: Please paste text as text, not images. I do not see any problems here. Please also add output of `ldd /usr/bin/zeal | grep local` to the question.

Comment: Hey I added output of commands above. check these

Comment: And what output you get if you execute simply `zeal`?

Comment: error message **Executable 'zeal' requires Qt 5.12.5, found Qt 5.12.4.**

Comment: It looks like you have local installation of Qt libraries. On clean 20.04 VM zeal works as expected. Then post full output of `ldd /usr/bin/zeal`.

Comment: Here is the output of command `ldd /usr/bin/zeal` and I never installed Qt in my system.

Comment: Some of your packages are still outdated - `libffi7`, `libicu63`. Please check the error output of `sudo apt-get update`, check your repositories (should have all pockets - *main*, *universe*, *multiverse*, *restricted*) and all update channels (*focal-updates*, *focal-secutiry*). Then run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to get all newest dependencies (save error logs if any). If error persists - install Aptitude with `sudo apt-get install aptitude` and share the output of `aptitude search ~o` and `dpkg -l | grep -v ^ii | grep -vE "^\||^\+|Desired"`.

Comment: `sudo apt dist-upgrade` worked for zeal but some softwares just gone like mendeley and when I restarted system it says **Oh no! Something has gone wrong** and freezed

Comment: Ok your solution worked. Ask system crash solved by [this ans](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748289/how-to-repair-ubuntu-installation-after-interrupted-dist-upgrade-without-losing). And mendeley, I will install it again. **Thanks a lot**

Comment: Great! So you can accept my edited answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your packages are still outdated - `libffi7`, `libicu63`. Please check the error output of `sudo apt-get update`, check your repositories (should have all pockets - *main*, *universe*, *multiverse*, *restricted*) and all update channels (*focal-updates*, *focal-secutiry*). Then run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to get all newest dependencies (save error logs if any).

Then use `zeal` deb-package from [the repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/zeal):

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get install zeal
```