# Reversing actions of apt-get remove

Tags: 18.04, server

I've done some things with `apt-get remove` and `apt-get install`, and one of the actions must have broken something on my Ubuntu 18.04 server

I'm wondering if someone has an idea as to how I would reverse/undo those changes, I can't boot into Ubuntu itself and can only boot into rescue mode

I've tried looking in the `/var/log/apt/history.log` file to check the apt-get history, but it doesn't exist in rescue mode

I need an alternative to just backing up data, as my internet is pretty slow and I don't want anything possibly getting corrupted if I timeout or having to start all over again

Comment: *install* and *remove* are designed to be "idempotent", meaning that *install foo* followed by *remove foo* will leave your system in exactly the same state that it was in before you started. There are two exceptions: Data files in /home and config files in /etc are not removed by *remove*...but those should both be inert anyway. We can offer you more specific advice if you [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1259082/edit) to provide more specifics on your problem.

Comment: All log files continue to exist regardless of whether you are in Rescue Mode or any other mode. Perhaps you are encountering a symptom?

Comment: I haven't only run `apt-get install foo` and `apt-get remove foo`
I've installed different components and removed other components, mostly python components if I remember correctly, which leads me to think maybe I messed something up with python that won't let me login via SSH properly

Comment: Some folks here are VERY good at troubleshooting ssh login problems. Why not ask about that instead?

Comment: Well its not like I've forgotten a password or something, I'm pretty sure me messing with python by uninstalling version 3.6 and installing version 3.8 broke it
I know this sounds dumb, but any time I installed the latest version, it output that I was using 3.6 when I just installed 3.8.3
So me being me, I uninstalled python3.6 hoping that would help, but it just led to these issues
While logging in though, it says `ssh: connect to host x port 22: Connection timed out`

Comment: Are your problems occurring on the SSH client or on the SSH server? Replacing the installed version of Python often breaks the system and ends badly, so we recommend against doing that. There are ways to use Py3.8 without uninstalling 3.6. One way or another, you must restore 3.6.

Comment: Yes, I figured that. But I've no idea how to do so in rescue mode, I've already tried installing it but I still can't get into the VPS. I've no idea if it starts properly as with the host all I see is Online and Offline

Comment: This seems like two different problems, but a combination of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/748350/411468) about fixing Ubuntu from recovery mode and [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/865644/411468) about using pyenv to manage non-system Python installations and keep from breaking the system (which I should also use, so thank you). Edit, for clarity -- replace "ubuntu-desktop" with "python3.6" in the recovery mode fixing.

Comment: When doing `apt-get install --reinstall python3.6`, I get an output saying the package doesn't exist

Comment: I've ran all the commands listed in that question, and I still cannot get into the VPS